# Java, adding modified string to ArrayList with foreach loop

Tags: java

I'm iterating through an ArrayList, modifying the string, and trying to add it to a new list.  It doesn't change the original list.  Within a foreach loop in Java, is it creating a copy of the object so I can add it?

```
List<String> newString = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (String s : lineOfWords {  // lineOfWords is a String that has text in it
   s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b", "$1"); 
   newString.add(s); 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I don't mean for it to change the original string, but to add the new string, in this case s, to my newString ArrayList.

Comment: It's not supposed to change the original list. Did you want that?

Comment: Your comment says lineOfWords was a String? Shouldn't it be a ArrayList<String>, according to your description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You original list is unchanged.

Your "s" variable is local to the loop, on entry to the body  loop it refers to the string in the original list, but then the s.replace() is returning a reference to a new String.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Strings are immutable.  So with the call to...

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b", "$1");
```

after this line executes, `s` is an entirely new String, not the one you started with.

**Update**
I hope `lineOfWords` is an array of String objects?  Not "a String that has text in it."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are creating a new String object each time you call `s.replaceAll`. You are then assigning that new String object to the temporary variable `s`, which has no effect on any strings that you have previously added to the `List` or on any strings in the original `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as String is immuatable any operation on it that modifies it actually creates a copy of it and in your loop assigning it to 's' will not change the original contents of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new string object when you perform the replace operation - as strings in Java are immutable.

You can see for yourself when objects are actually the same or not using the "==" operator, which compares references when used on objects. Since String is an object it has this reference comparison behaviour, but it is sometimes confused due to java interning strings to that in many cases two equal strings of characters actually refer to the same object.